# Error: "Driver [default] not supported." in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, caching, redis, laravel-8

I don't really know where the error is, for me, it's still a mystery. But I'm using Laravel 8 to produce a project, it was working perfectly and randomly started to return this error and all projects started to return this error too. I believe it's something with Redis, as I'm using it to store the system cache.
When I go to access my endpoint in postman it returns the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Driver [default] not supported. in file /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php on line 109

#0 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php(80): Illuminate\Support\Manager->createDriver('default')
#1 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(159): Illuminate\Support\Manager->driver()
#2 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(57): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->getSession(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#8 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(695): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(670): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(636): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#12 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(625): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 /var/www/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 /var/www/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#29 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /var/www/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 {main}
```

When I access this same endpoint in the browser, it returns this other error:

```
InvalidArgumentException
Driver [default] not supported.

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php:109

    protected function createDriver($driver) {
        // First, we will determine if a custom driver creator exists for the given driver and

        // if it does not we will check for a creator method for the driver. Custom creator
        // callbacks allow developers to build their own "drivers" easily using Closures.
        if (isset($this->customCreators[$driver])) {
            return $this->callCustomCreator($driver);
        } else {
            $method = 'create'.Str::studly($driver).'Driver';
            if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
                return $this->$method();
            }
        }
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Driver [$driver] not supported.");
    }

    /**
     * Call a custom driver creator.
     *
     * @param  string  $driver
     * @return mixed
     */

    protected function callCustomCreator($driver) {
        return $this->customCreators[$driver]($this->container);
    }

    /**
     * Register a custom driver creator Closure.
```

As I'm not sure where the error is, I'm not sure which part of the code I could put here, but if someone has already gotten an error like that, help me. I'm totally lost.

In my `.env` file I declared the

```
 SESSION_CONNECTION=session
 BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
 CACHE_DRIVER=redis
 REDIS_URL=redis
 QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
 SESSION_DRIVER=redis
 SESSION_LIFETIME=126
 SESSION_CONNECTION=session
 MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1
 REDIS_HOST=redis
 REDIS_PASSWORD=null
 REDIS_CLIENT = predis
 REDIS_PORT=6379
```

in my config\database.php file

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections set up for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [
        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open-source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [
        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '2'),
        ],
        'session' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => '1',
            'prefix' => 's:'
        ],
    ],
];
```

my config\session.php file

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
    |
    */
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */
    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where the session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "Redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */
    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */
    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache-Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | While using one of the framework's cache driven session backends you may
    | list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
    | must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
    |
    | Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
    |
    */
    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */
    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */
    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has an HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */
    'http_only' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | will set this value to "lax" since this is a secure default value.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
    |
    */
    'same_site' => 'lax',
];
```

Comment: It is related to the session as the previous file accessed before the error is `Illuminate\Support\Manager->driver()`, so check your `SESSION_DRIVER` in your `.env` file or `config/session.php`

Comment: @matiaslauriti I edited the post with my config files, could you see if you can see something wrong?

Comment: Do you have `SESSION_DRIVER=default` in your `.env`?  Available options are listed at the top of `config\session.php`

Comment: @keyboardSmasher Yes, my SESSION_DRIVER was default. I changed it to session, but the error continues, should I run a command?

Comment: @Mecaloop see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have set `SESSION_CONNECTION=session`, but your `SESSION_DRIVER=default`, so you have to use `SESSION_DRIVER=database` in your `.env`. See the `config/session.php`:

```php
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Session Database Connection
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
 | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
 | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
 |
 */

 'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),
```

Comment: I am using redis to store the cache and not the database. I changed, how do I update this information? I put more information about .env in the post.

Comment: Do you have a new error ? Can you update the question with it ?

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem. After configuring I ran the php artisan optimize command and the settings were updated.